# How to use and register local components inside App.vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite

I am using Laravel 10, Vite and Vue

I want to use two component inside my App.vue

Here is my App.vue file :

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <AppHeader></AppHeader>
            ... Content ...
            <AppFooter></AppFooter>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script setup>
    import AppHeader from "./components/partials/AppHeader.vue";
    import AppFooter from "./components/partials/AppFooter.vue";
    export default {
        components : {
            AppHeader,
            AppFooter,
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I get this error :

```
[vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc] <script setup> cannot contain ES module exports. If you are using a previous version of <script setup>, please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuej
s/rfcs/pull/227.

C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/rest_api/resources/js/components/App.vue
9  |  <script setup>
10 |  import AppHeader from "./components/partials/AppHeader.vue";
11 |  import AppFooter from "./components/partials/AppFooter.vue";
   |                                                               ^
12 |  export default {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
13 |      components : {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
14 |          AppHeader,
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
15 |          AppFooter,
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
16 |      }
   |  ^^^^^
17 |  }
   |  ^
```

Thanks

I am a total beginner in Vue and this code is from a Tutorial

Comment: `<script setup>` uses different syntax to `<script>` in vuejs3 - as usual, vuejs has very good [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) - basically, in your case, you can just remove the whole `export default { .... }` and it'll just work (keep the imports)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your help works for me but I changed

```
import AppHeader from "./components/partials/AppHeader.vue";
import AppHeader from "./components/partials/AppHeader.vue";
```

to

```
import AppHeader from "@/components/partials/AppHeader.vue";
import AppFooter from "@/components/partials/AppFooter.vue";
```

Comment: ok, welcome. 
`@` symbol is often configured as an alias for the src directory in a Vue project. This can be particularly useful in larger projects.